# Is it possible to store Minecraft not on a computer?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My computer is running low on space, but I really want to download Minecraft. Is it possible to download it on a USB, or even Google Drive?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I play Minecraft on a USB flash drive?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30744/can-i-play-minecraft-on-a-usb-flash-drive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be possible to run it from USB-drive or so, but as stated above, that could cause some issues. I don't think that most of the game data will be stored anywhere other than in your PC, since most of the data goes directly to the `%appdata%` directory.

Some third party applications however could be able to change that default saving directory.

Answer (score 6):

You may run into issues trying that, but you can.  In the minecraft executable, before you login you can click Edit Profile to change some settings.  You will need to run the minecraft.exe file from the external drive, because it also counts as the launcher.

When you edit the profile you are using to login (or create one for a new profile), you will see an option for Game Directory that lets you change the directory that minecraft installs to.  This could be a USB, but I don't know if it will work well with cloud based drives.

Minecraft doesn't take a lot of space up, but that is something you can try.

Comment: Just to add to this, if you do run Minecraft on a USB drive (either a flash drive or something bigger) you will experience lag as you explore and make changes to the world.  Most modern PCs and laptops have a fast read/write rate when compared to a USB drive since the technology used for internal drives and connections is different. (Wiki: SATA vs USB )  If you have USB3 ports and a USB3 drive, you should be fine with minimal lag.

Answer (score 2):

You can run it off an USB drive but do be aware that Minecraft will still use your hard drive to save the worlds. You won't be saving a lot of disk space.

Comment: There's external programs like [Magic Launcher](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/1262884-launcher-magic-launcher-1-3-1-mods-options) which allows you to select the location that the files are saved.