# Is There any way to Install Minecraft on a USB stick?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, linux

So I have a disk quota of around 1.979gb on my Linux installation, and I really want to play Minecraft. Currently, I have it installed and it runs fine, but I have a lot of files for school. I recently found a 32gb USB drive laying around and I wondered if I could transfer the .minecraft and minecraft-launcher folder to the USB drive, and run the minecraft launcher from the drive.

Also, for anyone who knows it, is there any way I can use the Lunar Client appimage and also put the .lunar files on the USB stick too?

Running Manjaro Linux BTW.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I play Minecraft on a USB flash drive?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30744/can-i-play-minecraft-on-a-usb-flash-drive)

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://www.instructables.com/How-To-Run-Minecraft-From-USB-Drive/) should help, even though it's for the old launcher, it should work if you know how to edit profiles in the new launcher. I don't think there's a way to convert a launcher profile to a file that you can use on a USB drive, but it should work.

If you're using the USB on a different OS from what you installed Minecraft on, you MAY have trouble running the game, but I'm not too sure about the inner-workings of the launcher and the game. This also applies to the launcher, but you should be able to just download the launcher from [minecraft.net/download](http://minecraft.net/download).

Comment: I have all the files downloaded, such as the .minecraft folder and all it's assets. Its just the matter of moving it to the USB drive... I don't think launcher profiles exist anymore.

Comment: They do, They're just titled installations now.

Comment: OHH, so just push all the .minecraft and launch files and profiles to the usb stick.... thats makes more sense. Thanks!

Comment: No, you just need to put the version you want (in the Versions folder) into the USB, then set the game directory to the version folder.